# 'reason' vs 'reason that'

Tags: grammaticality, difference

The complementiser **that** is the first word in a complement of a noun<sup>♦</sup>. When can it be omitted?
Do 1 and 2 below differ?

I am asking in general, but I exemplify with [Prof John Lawler's examples](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/180155/50720) modified by me:

> 1. He concealed the **reason that** he had robed.
>   2. He concealed the **reason** he had robed.

Please exclude and omit [reason why](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/119880/50720), about which I ask not because 'why' is redundant.

<sup>♦</sup>See [5][vi], p 176, *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* (2005) by Huddleston, Pullum.

Comment: At first blush,  I can't think of *any* instances where *that* is required in sentences of similar formation.  Of course there are other formations where *that* is ungrammatical following the noun *reason*:  She wouldn't listen to reason.  You disobeyed me- for what reason?

Comment: This would be helpful: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reason

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb: You can always omit *that* after *the reason* (i.e. ***the reason (that)***). Put it another way, wherever you can say ***the reason that***, you can omit *that*.

*That vs. Why*: You can use *that* (which is optional) in place of *why* but only in defining clauses, and make sure that you use *reason* not *reasons* (plural) if you want to use a *that*-clause. (See Cambridge Dictionary Online's note below.)

> Question: [W]hat are the similarities or differences between the two sentences below?
>
> 1. He didn't tell me **the reason that** he wore a polka-dot dress.
> 2. He didn't tell me **the reason** he wore a polka-dot dress.

Answer: There is no difference in meaning whatsoever.

---

**References<sup>†</sup>:**

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/reason_1) lists these uses of *reason*, among others:

> 1 [countable] a fact, situation, or intention that explains why something happened, why someone did something, or why something is true
>   **reason for:** *The police asked her the reason for her visit.*
>   **reason for doing something:** *Could you explain your reasons for choosing this particular course?*
>   **reason why:** *The reason why so many people caught the disease is still not clear.*
>   **reason (that):** *The reason these cars are so expensive is that they are largely built by hand.*
>   [...]

[Cambridge Dictionary Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reason) lists *reason why*, *reason that*, and *reason + to*-infinitive.

> ***Reason why*** We use *reason why* before a clause. We often omit *why*, especially in statements:
>   　　　*The **reason (why)** I didn’t contact you was that I was only in town for a few hours.*
>   ***Reason that*** We use *reason that* before a clause. We often omit *that*, especially in statements. *Reason that* is less common and slightly more formal than *reason why*:
>   　　　*The **reason (that)** we need new guidelines is that the present ones are just not working.*
>   　We do not use *reason* in the plural with a *that*-clause:
>   　　　*There are several **reasons why** I don’t like the book.
>
>   　　　Not: <del>There are several reasons that...</del>*
>   ***Reason + to*-infinitive** We can use reason with a to-infinitive:
>   　　　*There’s no **reason to be** suspicious – everything, is perfectly normal.*

*Longman English Grammar* (by L. G. Alexander) mentions *reason why*, *reason for which*, and *reason that* shortly.

> 1.38.3 **Reason**
>   **defining:**
>   ​　　　*That's **the reason (for which)** he dislikes me.*
>   ​　　　*That's **(the reason) why** he dislikes me.*
>   **non-defining:**
>   ​　　　***My success in business, (the reason) for which*** he dislikes me, has been due to hard work.
>   ​　　　***My success in business, the reason why*** he dislikes me, has been due to hard work. (*The reason* cannot be omitted before *why*.)
>
> 1.38.4 **('That') in place of 'when', 'where', 'why'**
>   *That* is possible (but optional) in place of *when*, *where* and *why* but only in defining clauses:
>   ​　　　[...]
>   ​　　　*That wasn't the reason **(that)** he lied to you* (*(That)* can be replaced by *why* or *for which*)

†<sub>Even though you've asked specifically for the exclusion of *reason why*, I decide to keep all alternatives--*reason why*, *reason that*, *reason for*, *reason for doing something*, *reason to do something*--in the above quoted texts, because it could, I believe, make this question more useful for the future reader.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Other than 'why', the sentence with 'that' seems a poor choice in this context. That is because the first clause says that he did not tell you; and you actually wanted a reason for that. It is **not a statement** where *that* works with 'the reason'. See this -

> We aren't going for **the simple reason that** we can't afford it -- the statement type structure

As for the sentence 2, I'd not prefer that at all. I'd use the format of `the reason for doing something` as OALD tells.

> **reason (for doing something)**: I have no particular ***reason for doubting*** him.

So,

> He didn't tell me ***the reason for wearing*** a polka-dot dress.

Comment: I apologise for any offense, but I removed your writing on 'reason why' because I should like this to be excluded. I wrote this in my original OP but strengthened my diction now.