# Structure of "reason that I was confused"

Tags: relative-clauses, complementation

What kind of structure does the sentence below have?

> The reason that I was confused is ...

Is **that I was confused** an adjective clause or not?

Also we can omit **that** and say: **the reason I was confused**.

Why can **that** be omitted?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/55507/3281

Comment: thanks. i found the answer. but i still don't get something here. what the link said is all about the "reason", but what about this sentence: the books (that) i am interested in are ... . doesn't this sentence have the same structure? isn't there a general structure?

Comment: The general structure that you're asking about is called a _relative clause_. There's more information in both my own and StoneyB's answers.

Answer (score 1):

This construction is idiomatic, and specific to the noun *reason*. A *that* clause following *reason* tells the hearer or listener what *reason* explains.

> The reason **that** I was confused *is equivalent to*
>   The reason **why** I was confused.

Both reflect the underlying fact

> I was confused because [*reason*].

And the reason why you may omit the *that* (or *why*) is that the clause headed by *that* (or *why*) is a special sort of relative clause; and just as in any other relative clause, with *that* or *who* or *which*, the "relativizer" which heads it may be omitted if it does not stand for the subject of the clause.

> The car { <s>that</s> / <s>which</s> } I am driving is a Toyota.
>   The reason { <s>that</s> / <s>why</s> } I was confused is that English is a horribly complicated language (just like all languages).

Answer (score 1):

> Is ***that I was confused*** an adjective clause or not?

It is a [relative clause](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/relative.htm); it begins with a relative pronoun (such as ***that***, for example) and defines/identifies the noun that precedes it (***reason*** in this case).

> Why can ***that*** be omitted [from *the reason **that** I was confused*]?

Because it is the object of the relative clause, one of the two occasions when it is proper to do so. There's more information about this [on this other web page](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/relative.htm).