# What's the difference between "reason for x", "reason why x", and "reason that"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What's the difference between

> **reason for** x
>   **reason why** x
>   **reason that**

Some examples are:

- The police asked her the reason for her visit.
- The reason why so many people caught the disease is still not clear
- The reason these cars are so expensive is that they are largely built by hand

Comment: Could you please give a couple examples of the usage you are thinking of, without any context this question is rather broad.

Comment: And it's probably more or less similar to this question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/55458/3281

Comment: @Peter examples added

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-nouns/reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three phrases can be used interchangeably depending on context.

In your usage

> reason for

is used to focus on motivation or existance

> The police asked her the ***reason for*** her visit.
>   The police asked her the ***reason why*** she visited.
>   The police asked her for the ***reason that*** she visited *(here)*.

> reason why

is used to focus on causality

> The ***reason why*** so many people caught the disease is still not clear.
>   The ***reason for*** so many people *catching* the disease is still not clear.
>   The ***reason that*** so many people caught the disease is still not clear.

> reason that

is used to explain why *something* happened or exists

> The ***reason that*** these cars are so expensive is because they are largely built by hand.
>   The ***reason why*** these cars are so expensive is because they are largely built by hand.
>   The ***reason for*** these cars *being* so expensive is because they are largely built by hand.

In each group of examples, the three sentences have the same meaning, the usage is basically stylistic.