# When can we say "the reason why" and "the reason for which" and when only "the reason"?

Tags: relative-pronouns, wh-questions, relative-adverbs, reasoning

I'm curious to find out when we can say "*the reason why*" and "*the reason for which*" and when only "*the reason*". Could you explain it to me please? I found some examples:

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-reason-why-noun-clause-or-adjective-clause.2559250/#post-12900537):
**(1a)** ***The reason** he left the house is obvious*. — natural
**(1b)** ***The reason why** he left the house is obvious*. — natural
**(1c)** ***The reason for which** he left the house is obvious*. — natural

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/do-you-know-the-reason-________-he-was-late.2747381/#post-13871638):
**(2a)** *This is **the reason** the legislation is adopted and it is, for the legislator, a dependent reason*. — natural
**(2b)** *This is **the reason why** the legislation is adopted and it is, for the legislator, a dependent reason*. — natural
**(2c)** *This is **the reason for which** the legislation is adopted and it is, for the legislator, a dependent reason*. — natural

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/do-you-know-the-reason-________-he-was-late.2747381/#post-13871638):
**(3a)** *Do you know **the reason** he was late*? — natural
**(3b)** *Do you know **the reason why** he was late*? — natural
**(3c)** *Do you know **the reason for which** he was late*? — unnatural

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-reason-for-which-he-doesnt-the-reason-he-doesnt-come-here-for.2505670/#post-12619320):
**(4a)** *Tell me **the reason** he doesn't come here*. — natural
**(4b)** *Tell me **the reason why** he doesn't come here*. — unnatural
**(4c)** *Tell me **the reason for which** he doesn't come here*. — unnatural

[wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-reason-for-which-vs-the-reason-that.2869004/#post-14505733):
**(5a)** ***The reason** the airlines have delayed flights is that a missile landed*... — natural
**(5b)** ***The reason why** the airlines have delayed flights is that a missile landed*... — unnatural
**(5c)** ***The reason for which** the airlines have delayed flights is that a missile landed*... — unnatural

Comment: You can safely omit both **why** and **for which** in all your examples. They are redundant. Alternatively, you can replace them with **that**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between "reason for x", "reason why x", and "reason that"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109624/whats-the-difference-between-reason-for-x-reason-why-x-and-reason-that)

Answer (score 1):

When using 'the reason', 'why' and 'for which' are entirely optional.

You can also use 'that'.

As they are unnecessary, each of the additions tends to make the sentence formal, or even stilted.

Comment: You wrote: "When using 'the reason', 'why' and 'for which' are entirely optional." That means all b- and c-variants are equally natural to you, right?

Comment: @lovii Natural, yes, but unnecessary, and (opinion), probably best used sparingly.

Comment: @PRL75 Surely, you find "*The **reason for which** the airlines have delayed flights is that a missile landed*" to be unnatural. No? It's awful

Comment: @gotube I agree it's not pleasant, but I wouldn't characterise it as unnatural.